# Issues with Artifactory after upgrade to 3.4

Tags: artifactory

I followed the [upgrade notes](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-Upgradingfromv2.6.6andAbovetov3.x) to upgrade from Artifactory 2.6.6 to 3.4.2, I reimported the artifacts but after that, artifact resolution often fails with 404.

Even previously deployed artifacts can not be resolved. The deploying Jenkins job runs fine, but when I open the URL from the log, I get that message:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Artifact not found: my/group/myapp/0.9.13-SNAPSHOT/myapp-0.9.13-SNAPSHOT.pom"
  } ]
}
```

I also tried to export/import the whole system after upgrade, but nothing changed.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does the failing artifact exist in Artifactory? in you can check the maven-metadata.xml and see if it is valid and contains the correct SNAPSHOT versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue is related to the unique snapshot behaviour of Maven 3. In fact, there is no `myapp-0.9.13-SNAPSHOT.pom`, but one with a timestamp. The Rest API does not cover that and not all Jenkins plugins have support for that.